# Vue router keep alive nested components after changing pages

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

Example of my issue here: https://jsfiddle.net/guanzo/myn5o94e/1/

1. App defaults to `/bar`.
2. Click "Go to bar child" which navigates to `/bar/barchild` and creates the `BarChild` component.
3. Click "Go to Foo" which navigates to `/foo`
4. Click "Go to bar". Bar child has disappeared.

Both `Foo` and `Bar` are "pages". How do i keep `BarChild` alive inside `Bar` when i switch between pages?

I know why `BarChild` disappears, it's because "Go to bar" links to `/bar`. But i don't know how to implement my desired behavior.

Answer (score 3):

Looks like you want the app to remember last visited child route of `/bar`. This is not what [`keep-alive`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#keep-alive) was supposed to do.

I suggest you to introduce a centralized store to save the data you want to remember and retrieve later. It could be as easy as another `new Vue` instance, or **vuex** for more complicated product. You could read [**this page**](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/state-management.html#Simple-State-Management-from-Scratch) from official docs for more details.